# Having trouble with equals operator. Finishing with exit code 11

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, nodes, equals, operator-keyword

Can somebody help me figure out what is wrong with my =operator? Without these two functions, my program runs perfectly but once they are implemented it results in the error finished with exit code 11.

I am trying to set two linked lists equal to each other.

```
virticalList::virticalList(const virticalList &p2) {
    *this=p2;
}

virticalList & virticalList::operator=(const virticalList& p2)
{
    Node* temp = p2.head->getNext();
    head = new Node(p2.head->getValue(),0);
    Node* curr = head;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        curr->setNext(new Node());
        curr->getNext()->setValue(temp->getValue());
        temp = temp->getNext();
    }
    return *this;
}
```

The problem I think is in my operator = function. Or in the private member head.

Here is my full virticalList class:

```
class virticalList
{
private:
    Node* head = new Node();
public:
    virticalList();
    void print();
    void virtInc();
    ~virticalList();
    virticalList(const virticalList &p2);
    virticalList& operator=(const virticalList& p2);
};

virticalList::virticalList()
{
    head -> setValue(10);

    Node * ptr = head;
    for(int i = 10; i<20; i++)
    {
        ptr -> setNext(new Node());
        ptr -> getNext()->setValue(i);
        ptr -> getNext()->setNext(nullptr);
        ptr = ptr -> getNext();
    }
}

virticalList::~virticalList() {
    Node * des = head;
    Node * d = des->getNext();
    while(des -> getNext()->getValue()!=NULL){
        delete des;
        des = d;
        if(d->getNext()!= nullptr){
            d = d->getNext();
        }
    }
}

void virticalList::print()
{
     Node * print = head;
    while(print -> getNext()->getValue()!=NULL){
         cout << print -> getValue() << " ";
         print = print -> getNext();
     }
     cout << "\n";
}

void virticalList::virtInc()
{
    Node * inc = head;
    while(inc -> getNext()->getValue()!=NULL){
        inc -> setValue(inc -> getValue()+1);
        inc = inc -> getNext();
    }
}

virticalList::virticalList(const virticalList &p2) {
    *this=p2;
}

virticalList & virticalList::operator=(const virticalList& p2)
{
    Node* temp = p2.head->getNext();
    head = new Node(p2.head->getValue(),0);
    Node* curr = head;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        curr->setNext(new Node());
        curr->getNext()->setValue(temp->getValue());
        temp = temp->getNext();
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Here is also my node class for reference:

```
class Node
        {
        private:
            int value;
            Node* next;
        public:
            Node();
            Node(int v, Node * next);
            void setValue(int v);
            int getValue();
            Node* getNext();
            void setNext(Node* theNewNext);
        };

Node::Node()
{
    next = 0;
    value = 0;
}
Node::Node(int v, Node * next_in)
{
    value = v;next = next_in;
}
void Node::setValue(int v)
{
    value = v;
}
int Node::getValue()
{
    return value;
}
Node* Node::getNext()
{
    return next;
}
void Node::setNext(Node* theNewNext)
{
    next = theNewNext;
}
```

Comment: So if you think you know the error cause, have you tried using an [mre]? Also is exit code 11 all you get for the error? Because as seen here: [Why should I post complete errors? Why isn't the message itself enough?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/12672179) a complete error message is better

Comment: There is still the memory leak in the code as it was earlier today. However that should not cause it to crash.

Comment: @TheGrandJ yes the only error I get is exit code 11

Comment: `operator=` sets up a list with exactly 2 nodes (and leaks a bunch of nodes in the process), regardless of how many nodes are in `p2`. Yet various member functions, such as `print()`, expect the list to contain at least 10 nodes; otherwise they plow right through a null pointer.

Comment: The bug that causes the crash could be a result of the several functions that expect the list to have 10 or more nodes. The loop in the destructor has the same 10 node dependency which could cause additional undefined behavior.

Comment: @drescherjm I have tried to get rid of the 10 node dependency, still same issue.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have tried to get rid of the 10 node dependency, still same issue.

Comment: I think you need to use a debugger to see where it crashes.

Comment: Why is everyone talking about `crash`? If you `return 11;` from your `main()` - you'd get exit code 11...

Comment: Now the destructor relies on the last node having a value of 0 - but you don't actually set up any node with a value of 0.

Comment: There are numerous possible causes of the error in that code.  Several functions call `getNext()` multiple times, without checking that it has returned null - after which each call has undefined behaviour.   It is also rather unusual practice for a copy constructor (which is used to initialise an object, who's lifetime starts after the constructor completes) to call that class's `operator=()` function (which assumes that `*this` is a previously constructed object).   A more usual approach (e.g copy and swap idiom) is for the assignment operator to use the copy constructor.

Comment: Since `c++11` we have `nullptr` instead of `NULL`

Comment: Can you please [stop spamming the same duplicate question repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65014163/issue-with-operator-resulting-in-exit-code-11)? There is a reason your previous question was downvoted and closed. You will not fix the problem by posting the same thing again.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that was a dumb approach of me haha but what if I do it while the next node is not null

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a duplicate question.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Sorry I did not realize editing a question would repost it. It's my first question.

Comment: No, you did not edit your first question. You explicitly deleted your first question, and then you copy/pasted and posted a new question. All this does for you is attract more downvotes, and unless this is corrected, Stackoverflow will, at some point, block you from posting any new questions. Before posting their first question on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question; which gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code shown has a lot of mistakes in it.  I see memory leaks.  I see loops that are not iterating nodes correctly and will eventually dereference `nullptr`s.  I see the copy constructor is implemented to call `operator=` rather than the other way around.

I would suggest rewriting the whole thing, for example:

```cpp
class Node
{
private:
    int value = 0;
    Node* next = nullptr;

public:
    Node(int v = 0, Node* n = nullptr);
    int getValue() const;
    void setValue(int v);
    Node* getNext() const;
    void setNext(Node* n);
};

Node::Node(int v, Node* n) :
    value(v),
    next(n)
{
}

int Node::getValue() const
{
    return value;
}

void Node::setValue(int v)
{
    value = v;
}

Node* Node::getNext() const
{
    return next;
}

void Node::setNext(Node* n)
{
    next = n;
}
```

```cpp
class virticalList
{
private:
    Node* head = nullptr;

public:
    virticalList();
    virticalList(const virticalList &p2);
    ~virticalList();

    virticalList& operator=(const virticalList& p2);

    void print() const;
    void virtInc();
};
```

```cpp
virticalList::virticalList() :
    head(new Node(10))
{
    Node* ptr = head;
    for(int i = 11; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        ptr->setNext(new Node(i));
        ptr = ptr->getNext();
    }
}

virticalList::virticalList(const virticalList &p2) {
    if (p2.head) {
        Node* temp = p2.head;
        Node* curr = head = new Node(temp->getValue());
        while (temp = temp->getNext()) {
            curr->setNext(new Node(temp->getValue()));
            curr = curr->getNext();
        }
    }
}

virticalList::~virticalList() {
    Node* ptr = head, *next;
    while (ptr) {
        next = ptr->getNext();
        delete ptr;
        ptr = next;
    }
}

virticalList& virticalList::operator=(const virticalList& p2)
{
    if (this != &p2) {
        virticalList temp(p2);
        //std::swap(head, temp.head);
        Node* ptr = head;
        head = temp.head;
        temp.head = ptr;
    }
    return *this;
}

void virticalList::print() const
{
    Node* ptr = head;
    while (ptr) {
        cout << ptr->getValue() << " ";
        ptr = ptr->getNext();
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

void virticalList::virtInc()
{
    Node* ptr = head;
    while (ptr) {
        ptr->setValue(ptr->getValue()+1);
        ptr = ptr->getNext();
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/y25AYP)

If you make `virticalList` be a `friend` of `Node` so `virticalList` can access the `Node::next` member directly, you can simplify the `virticalList` constructors a little bit:

```cpp
class Node
{
private:
    int value = 0;
    Node* next = nullptr;

public:
    Node(int v = 0, Node* n = nullptr);
    int getValue() const;
    void setValue(int v);
    Node* getNext() const;
    void setNext(Node* n);

    friend class virticalList;
};

Node::Node(int v, Node* n) :
    value(v),
    next(n)
{
}

int Node::getValue() const
{
    return value;
}

void Node::setValue(int v)
{
    value = v;
}

Node* Node::getNext() const
{
    return next;
}

void Node::setNext(Node* n)
{
    next = n;
}
```

```cpp
class virticalList
{
private:
    Node* head = nullptr;

public:
    virticalList();
    virticalList(const virticalList &p2);
    ~virticalList();

    virticalList& operator=(const virticalList& p2);

    void print() const;
    void virtInc();
};
```

```cpp
virticalList::virticalList()
{
    Node** ptr = &head;
    for(int i = 10; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        *ptr = new Node(i);
        ptr = &((*ptr)->next);
    }
}

virticalList::virticalList(const virticalList &p2) {
    Node** curr = &head;
    Node* temp = p2.head;
    while (temp) {
        *curr = new Node(temp->getValue());
        curr = &((*curr)->next);
        temp = temp->getNext();
    }
}

virticalList::~virticalList() {
    Node* ptr = head, *next;
    while (ptr) {
        next = ptr->getNext();
        delete ptr;
        ptr = next;
    }
}

virticalList& virticalList::operator=(const virticalList& p2)
{
    if (this != &p2) {
        virticalList temp(p2);
        //std::swap(head, temp.head);
        Node* ptr = head;
        head = temp.head;
        temp.head = ptr;
    }
    return *this;
}

void virticalList::print() const
{
    Node* ptr = head;
    while (ptr) {
        cout << ptr->getValue() << " ";
        ptr = ptr->getNext();
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

void virticalList::virtInc()
{
    Node* ptr = head;
    while (ptr) {
        ptr->setValue(ptr->getValue()+1);
        ptr = ptr->getNext();
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/MSidjj)